# SQL update one column from another column in another table

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update

I read various post's prior to this. but none of them seemed to work for me.

As the title suggests, I am trying to update one column from a column in another table. I don't recall having problems with this before..

**1.** Table: user_settings.contact_id, I want to update with contacts.id `where (user_settings.account_id == contacts_account_id)`

**2.** Previously Contacts were linked to user accounts via the account_id. However, now we want to link a contact to `user_settings` via `contacts.id`

Below are a few examples of what I have tried, though none of them have worked. I would be interested in A.) Why they don't work and B.) What should I do instead.

Example A:

```
UPDATE user_settings
SET user_settings.contact_id = contacts.id 
FROM user_settings 
INNER JOIN contacts ON user_settings.account_id = contacts.account_id
```

Example B:

```
UPDATE (SELECT A.contact_id id1, B.id id2
  FROM user_settings A, contacts B
  WHERE user_settings.account_id = contacts.account_id)
SET id1 = id2
```

Example C:

```
UPDATE user_settings
SET user_settings.contact_id = (SELECT id
  FROM contacts
  WHERE (user_settings.account_id = contacts.account_id)
WHERE EXISTS ( user_settings.account_id = contacts.account_id )
```

I feel like my brain just shutdown on me and would appreciate any bumps to reboot it. Thanks :)

Comment: Can someone tell my why this got voted down so I can avoid it in the future?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

According to MySQL documentation, to do a cross table update, you can't use a join (like in other databases), but instead use a where clause:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

I think something like this should work:

```
UPDATE User_Settings, Contacts
    SET User_Settings.Contact_ID = Contacts.ID
    WHERE User_Settings.Account_ID = Contacts.Account_ID
```

Comment: Thanks I definitely just mixed up my databases. As soon as you typed that gears started churning.

Comment: your answer was exactly what i was looking for. if you change the table and column names to match mine, it may make the answer better match the question. Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

```
Update tabelName Set SanctionLoad=SanctionLoad Where ConnectionId=ConnectionID
go
update tabelName  Set meterreading=meterreading where connectionid=connectionid
go
update tabelName  set customername=setcustomername where customerid=customerid
```

Comment: Would be nice to have some context, e.g. explaining the go-keyword. I realize the answer is now 8 years old, but still.