# mysql update value from another column in the same table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table with these 2 columns : date and day
date has dates and day is empty
I would like to do something like this :

```
UPDATE table SET day='day(date)'
```

the idea is to take the date (its in date time format) and take out the day and insert it into the day column. any ideas ?

Comment: Can you given an example? I am confused by day date description.

Comment: Try checking out this question/answer

<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818512/sql-update-one-column-from-another-column-in-another-table>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will help

```
UPDATE table SET day = EXTRACT(DAY FROM date)
```