# Updating a column from another column conditioned on related table

Tags: mysql, join

I've run into a problem where I'd like to copy data between columns based on a condition from a related table.  Looking at the top answer from eglasius on this similar problem [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7817007/sql-set-values-of-one-column-equal-to-values-of-another-column-in-the-same-table)  I came up with this solution:

```
UPDATE table1 SET table1.column2 = table2.column1 
FROM table1 NATURAL JOIN table2 
WHERE table2.column1 = "myCondition"
```

This query gave me a syntax error beginning at `FROM` although replacing the `UPDATE` clause with a `SELECT` seemed to yield no problems.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in the case of an `UPDATE` mySQL appears to dislike a `FROM` syntax.  I had good success moving the join to the front of the query, following it with the `JOIN` and finally the `WHERE` condition, like this:

```
UPDATE table1 NATURAL JOIN table2
SET table1.column2 = table1.column1
WHERE table2.column1 = "myCondition"
```

Comment: I owe this solution in part to @Eric for his answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818512/sql-update-one-column-from-another-column-in-another-table)